# Disable caching on specific model in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Basically I want to be able to have a count value in the active admin navigation bar, that updates according to a query. But it seems like the registered models are cached, and thereby also the navigation label provided by the registered model.

Is it possible to change this default caching behaviour?

```
ActiveAdmin.register ChangeRequest do
  config.sort_order = "created_at_desc"

  actions :all, except: [:show]

  menu label: "Change Requests (#{ChangeRequest.pending.count})"

  ....
end
```

If possible, the "menu label:" should be updated on every reload...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ajax for this purpose.

> Assuming you have a model name `Change Request`

Add a collection action in `admin/change_request` controller

```
  collection_action :total_pending do
    render json: { total: ChangeRequest.pending.count }
  end
```

in your `active_admin.js.coffee` file add this ajax call

```
  $.ajax
    url: '/en/admin/change_requests/total_pending'
    success: (data) ->
      $('#change_requests a').text("Custom text #{data.total}")
```

> NOTE: HTML element id and URL can be different as per your model &
>   controller names

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I do not think it is the query that is cached, I think it is the string that contains the result of the query that is cached :(

Comment: that's a bummer!! @Tobias let me find something else for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe proc will work here?

```
menu label: proc{"Change Requests (#{ChangeRequest.pending.count})"}
```